# In C#, how can I get the name of the calling project from within a referenced project?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, reflection, log4net, log4net-configuration

I have three projects: My.Business, My.WebSite and My.WebService

I need my logging class to be able to identify when a request is made from the website versus the web service. I used to have the web service running as a separate application underneath the web site, so I'd just use different config files, which worked fine. But I want the web service now to run under the same application.

If I could figure out if the request was coming from My.WebSite or My.WebService, I'd be set, but I'm not sure how to do this.

- Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly() returns back My.Business
- Assembly.GetEntryAssembly() is null
- I could check the StackTrace, but that seems sloppy and how for back would I have to go? Especially because the logging may be triggered by code in My.Business that was originally invoked from one of the other projects.

Since the web service requests end in ".asmx", the following concept works, but it just doesn't feel right.

```
return HttpContext.Current.Request.Path.IndexOf(".asmx") >= 0 ? "My.WebService" : "My.WebSite";
```

Thanks!

Comment: I would say you could do with some inversion of control here; The My.Business classes should be "given" the information they need to work (in different manners), rather than trying to find it... what if you introduce a 3rd application... now you have to change My.Business again.

Comment: I considered this, but logging occurs in all three projects. So I'm not sure how to have My.Business do logging and pass in information about whether to log to the WebSite or WebService.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use Assembly.GetCallingAssembly():

```
return Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().FullName;
```

This will return the assembly that invoked the current executing method, so you can capture whoever is calling into your My.Business assembly that way.

With that said, I tend to agree with the comment above by Meirion Hughes.  You might like to consider passing in any info that is required to your logging class, especially if it is likely to be used across more applications in the future.

Comment: That's returning back My.Business

Comment: Also, I don't want the assembly that invoked the current executing method, because logging could have been triggered from a function within My.Business. I want it to know whether My.WebSite or My.WebService initiated it.

Comment: I'm guessing it's returning 'My.Business' because, as you've described in your second comment, your logging method isn't an entry point to your assembly.  You could capture the calling assembly when you instantiate your BLL object as a private member or property and refer to it as needed.

Answer (score 0):

`this.GetType().Assembly.FullName` will give you the name of the assembly name for the current class.